# Pop-up for view bulk operation?

Tags: 7, views, javascript, actions

Normally View Bulk Operation (VBO) will lead to separate page for asking details and performing actions.

Is there any module readily available to show pop-up for views bulk operations. Searches did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You may check my post [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130184/drupal-popup-module-is-not-working-in-custom-front-page/130185#130185). You can apply your condition. I think this may help you to solve your query.